# Magic keyboard not connecting (Neither in FileVault screen nor normal OS)

Tags: macos, keyboard, bluetooth

I have a magic keyboard which came with an iMac (Late 2009).  Until recently it worked like a charm but now each time I power on the iMac, the keyboard isn't connecting. Neither in the FileVault screen nor after in the normal OS.

Unfortunately, the fix is quite annoying:

- Connect a USB Keyboard.
- Go to Bluetooth preferences and remove the keyboard.
- Power-off the keyboard by pressing the power button for a while.
- Reset the keyboard by pressing the power button until the keyboard light flashes.

At that point, the iMac recognizes the keyboard and works as usual. Even if the iMac goes to sleep, the keyboard works fine afterwards.

Additional info:

- OS: High Sierra
- FileVault enabled
- Keyboard running on rechargeable batteries.

Any idea what is happening and how to fix it in a more permanent way?

PD: I found some posts around about problems with bluetooth devices and FileVault.  Could be the problem related to this?

Comment: Just wondering, did this change in behaviour begin at the same time as another change in your environment? For example, any new  software or hardware? No new Wi-Fi modems or routers, or even a new microwave?

Comment: Nothing I can remember.  I'm updating the question as this is not really happening at wake-up, but in the Filevault authentication screen.

Comment: have you reset SMC on your iMac?

Comment: Yes, I tried the usual stuff (reseting SMC, removing & resetting bluetooth devices, ...

Comment: I'm trying to disable FileVault, remove all the bluetooth devices and start from scratch until FileVault was again active.  Will report if it works